# BookStore class with nullpointer exceptio null, I honestly thought my code was perfect

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

so I am doing an assignment and I finished everything, then when I did the run test, hell broke loose and I couldn't find out what I need to change.

```
public class BookStore
{
    private String storeName;
    private Book[] inventory;

public String[] getBookTitlesContaining(String wordInTitle)
{    
    int i = 0;
    String[] bookTitle = new String[i];        
    for (Book tempBook : inventory)
    {
        if(tempBook.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(wordInTitle))
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    int j = 0;
    bookTitle = new String[i];
    for (Book tempBook : inventory)
    {
        if(tempBook.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(wordInTitle))
        {
            bookTitle[j] = tempBook.getTitle();
            j++;
        }
    }
    if ((wordInTitle == null) || (wordInTitle == "") || (i == 0)) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    return bookTitle;
}
```

I am positive this is the method my run test is referring too, but I guess it can be many things. I guess I should put rest of the code here (Warning super long)

but the error was

```
        String[] titles = bookStore.getBookTitlesContaining("THE");
        System.out.println(8 == titles.length); // this line
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

my whole code is here, feel free to browse through, sorry if its super long

```
public class BookStore
{
    private String storeName;
    private Book[] inventory;
/**
 * Main Constructor
 * initiate inventory Array
 * input data in inventory
 */
public BookStore()
{
    inventory = new Book[20];     

    Date tempDate0 = new Date(2016,1,1);                
    inventory[0] = new Book(new Author(new Name("James", "Joyce", null ), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "ULYSSES");
    inventory[1] = new Book(new Author(new Name("F.", "Fitzgerald","Scott"), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "THE GREAT GATSBY");
    inventory[2] = new Book(new Author(new Name("James", "Joyce", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "A PORTRAIT OF THE ARTIST AS A YOUNG MAN");
    inventory[3] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Vladimir", "Nabokov", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "LOLITA");
    inventory[4] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Aldous", "Huxley", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "BRAVE NEW WORLD");
    inventory[5] = new Book(new Author(new Name("William", "Faulkner", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "THE SOUND AND THE FURY");
    inventory[6] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Joseph", "Heller", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "CATCH-22");
    inventory[7] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Arthur", "Koestler", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "DARKNESS AT NOON");
    inventory[8] = new Book(new Author(new Name("D.", "Lawrence", "H."), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "SONS AND LOVERS");
    inventory[9] = new Book(new Author(new Name("John", "Steinbeck", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "THE GRAPES OF WRATH");
    inventory[10] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Malcolm", "Lowry", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "UNDER THE VOLCANO");
    inventory[11] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Samuel", "Butler", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "THE WAY OF ALL FLESH");
    inventory[12] = new Book(new Author(new Name("George", "Orwell", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "1984");
    inventory[13] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Robert", "Graves", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "I, CLAUDIUS");
    inventory[14] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Virginia", "Woolf", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "TO THE LIGHTHOUSE");
    inventory[15] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Theodore", "Dreiser", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "AN AMERICAN TRAGEDY");
    inventory[16] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Carson", "McCullers", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "THE HEART IS A LONELY HUNTER");
    inventory[17] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Kurt", "Vonnegut", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0,"SLAUGHTERHOUSE-FIVE");
    inventory[18] = new Book(new Author(new Name("George", "Orwell", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "ANIMAL FARM");
    inventory[19] = new Book(new Author(new Name("W.", "Maugham", "Somerset"), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "OF HUMAN BONDAGE");

}
/**
 * secondary Constructor
 * iniate and store array Inventory
 * @param store value if storeName does not equal taylor's used book
 * else storeName equals jason's used book
 */
public BookStore(String storeName)
{
    inventory = new Book[20];       
    Date tempDate0 = new Date(2016,1,1);                
    inventory[0] = new Book(new Author(new Name("James", "Joyce", null ), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "ULYSSES");
    inventory[1] = new Book(new Author(new Name("F.", "Fitzgerald","Scott"), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "THE GREAT GATSBY");
    inventory[2] = new Book(new Author(new Name("James", "Joyce", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "A PORTRAIT OF THE ARTIST AS A YOUNG MAN");
    inventory[3] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Vladimir", "Nabokov", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "LOLITA");
    inventory[4] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Aldous", "Huxley", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "BRAVE NEW WORLD");
    inventory[5] = new Book(new Author(new Name("William", "Faulkner", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "THE SOUND AND THE FURY");
    inventory[6] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Joseph", "Heller", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "CATCH-22");
    inventory[7] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Arthur", "Koestler", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "DARKNESS AT NOON");
    inventory[8] = new Book(new Author(new Name("D.", "Lawrence", "H."), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "SONS AND LOVERS");
    inventory[9] = new Book(new Author(new Name("John", "Steinbeck", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "THE GRAPES OF WRATH");
    inventory[10] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Malcolm", "Lowry", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "UNDER THE VOLCANO");
    inventory[11] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Samuel", "Butler", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "THE WAY OF ALL FLESH");
    inventory[12] = new Book(new Author(new Name("George", "Orwell", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "1984");
    inventory[13] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Robert", "Graves", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "I, CLAUDIUS");
    inventory[14] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Virginia", "Woolf", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "TO THE LIGHTHOUSE");
    inventory[15] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Theodore", "Dreiser", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "AN AMERICAN TRAGEDY");
    inventory[16] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Carson", "McCullers", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "THE HEART IS A LONELY HUNTER");
    inventory[17] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Kurt", "Vonnegut", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0,"SLAUGHTERHOUSE-FIVE");
    inventory[18] = new Book(new Author(new Name("George", "Orwell", null), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "ANIMAL FARM");
    inventory[19] = new Book(new Author(new Name("W.", "Maugham", "Somerset"), tempDate0, tempDate0, null), tempDate0, "OF HUMAN BONDAGE");

    setStoreName(storeName);
}
/**
 * @return book store name
 */
public String getStoreName()
{
    return storeName;
}
/**
 * @param store value if storeName does not equal taylor's used book
 * else storeName equals jason's used book
 */
public void setStoreName(String storeName)
{
    if(storeName != null && !storeName.equals("Taylor's Used Books"))
    {
        this.storeName = storeName;
    }
    else
    {
        this.storeName = "Jason's Used Books";
    }
}
/**
 * @return inventory array
 */
public Book[] getInventory()
{
    return inventory;
}
/**
 * @param inventory cannot be null
 */
public void setInventory(Book[] inventory)
{
    if(inventory != null)
    {
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }
}
/**
 * method, return the number of books a particular last name of an author wrote
 */
public int howManyBooksDidThisAuthorWrite(String authorLastName) //if statement
{
    int count = 0;        
    for(Book a : inventory)
    {
        if(a.getAuthorName().equalsIgnoreCase(authorLastName))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
/**
 * method get author's full name based on title
 */
public String getAuthorFullName(String title) //wtf is this
{
    for(Book a : inventory)
    {
        if(a.getTitle() != null && a.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title))

        {
            return a.getAuthorName();
        }
    }
    return null;

}
/**
 * method get array of books written by the author of such lastName
 */
public Book[] getBooksWrittenBy(String authorLastName)
{    
    int count = 0;        
    for(Book tempBook : inventory)
    {
        if(tempBook != null)
        {
            if(tempBook.getAuthor().getName().getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(authorLastName))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }           
    Book[] someBook = new Book[count];
    int i = 0;
    for(Book tempBook : inventory)
    {
        if(tempBook.getAuthor().getName().getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(authorLastName))
            {
                someBook[i] = tempBook;
                i++;
            }
    }

    return someBook;
}
/**
 * method get books written by the author's first name
 */
public Book getBookWrittenBy(String firstName)
{
    for(int i=0; i<inventory.length; i++)
    {
        if(inventory[i] != null && inventory[i].getAuthor().getName().getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName))
        {
            return inventory[i];            
        }
    }
    return null;
}
/**
 * get books with titles containing certain words
 */
public String[] getBookTitlesContaining(String wordInTitle)
{    
    int i = 0;
    String[] bookTitle = new String[i];        
    for (Book tempBook : inventory)
    {
        if(tempBook.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(wordInTitle))
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    int j = 0;
    bookTitle = new String[i];
    for (Book tempBook : inventory)
    {
        if(tempBook.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(wordInTitle))
        {
            bookTitle[j] = tempBook.getTitle();
            j++;
        }
    }
    if ((wordInTitle == null) || (wordInTitle == "") || (i == 0)) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    return bookTitle;
}
```

}

Comment: You should _never_ change a question once people start answering, in a way that falsifies their answers.  I will roll it back.  Three people gave you correct answers to your original question.  If you now have a different question, then ask a new question.

Comment: With all due respect, I have never changed my question, I was simply questioning my mistakes that you claimed to not be mistake.

Answer (score 0):

With this execution

```
    String[] titles = bookStore.getBookTitlesContaining("THE");
    System.out.println(8 == titles.length); // this line
```

I'm pretty sure that the variable "i" will get a value of 0 after the search.

```
    if(tempBook.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(wordInTitle))
```

The reason being the comparison with "toLowerCase". The only value getting lowercased is the one in inventory, while the search key is used as is ("THE" in this case)
Probably would be better to use toLowerCase in both operands.

```
    if(tempBook.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(wordInTitle.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get what you are saying, but that didn't fix it. I also tried to create an object (I am using blueJ) it did fix the problem (it was null before, now 8) but I am still getting error in that line.

Comment: Then try to debug it, check what value is being returned, and in the method logic what conditions raises that return. e.g The value of i, wordInTitle and bookTitle. That should help you troubleshoot your problem. If there are new findings let us know

Comment: Actually, I forgot to clear my test assignmern window, it passed already! SORRY! lol

Comment: There you go, glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

When this condition fires

```
if ((wordInTitle == null) || (wordInTitle == "") || (i == 0)) 
{
    return null;
}
```

the method returns null.  In your test code

```
String[] titles = bookStore.getBookTitlesContaining("THE");
System.out.println(8 == titles.length);
```

you're taking that `null` value, and trying to look up its `length`.  But a `null` doesn't have a `length`, so this fails.

You should really remove this section entirely.

```
if ((wordInTitle == null) || (wordInTitle == "") || (i == 0)) 
{
    return null;
}
```

Without that section, your method will return an empty array, which is fine, because an empty array has a length of zero.

Also, realise that you're searching the lower case version of each title for `"THE"`.  This will never be found, because `"THE"` is not in any lower case string.

Comment: wait, by inputting "THE", my if statement that returns null shouldn't fire anything, because i != 0, wordinTitle is not null, its "THE" - also I did try removing that statement, didn't fix the problem. and will update the getLowerCase to my code.

Comment: The `if` fires because `i==0` at that point.  The word was _not_ found, so `i` never changed. Incidentally, `==` isn't the right operator to compare strings with.

Comment: how is i == 0 at that count? i is an int that I defined in the beginning, it is index. I did my foreach and i only initiated as zero.

Comment: It's 0 because you set it to 0 at the start of the loop, and you never changed it.

Comment: there was something called... i++;

Comment: And the `i++` was inside an `if` that never came true.  At least in the original version of your code.  I see now that you've changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((wordInTitle == null) || (wordInTitle == "") || (i == 0)) 
{
    return null;
}
```

Err ... if i==0 (means that no books have been found), you return null. So the titles array after the method call is null.

EDITED: I read that you believe that i is not 0. But it is:

```
if(tempBook.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(wordInTitle))
```

You convert the title of the book to lowercase, but "wordInTitle" is "THE" (uppercase). This will NEVER MATCH.

But nevertheless it's no good idea to return null here, anyway!

After all it's no good idea to return null in this case. I'd encourage you to return always an array, even if this array is empty.

Also I'd like to encourage you to use a debugger for such cases. I mean, I have no problem posting the answer, but you don't want to be dependend on Stackoverflow all the time, don't you? ;-)

It's easy to find out the problem by using a debugger, and you really should try to use it.